# How to know which uiview user is using

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, uialertview, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm implementing push notification and i'm managing it when user is using app. So an alert view appear and on view click it must redirect to an uiview. now if user is showing that uiview when alert is coming how can i know the uiview on top? how can i update the uiview current? Alert is shown in application delegate in the metod didReceiveRemoteNotification.
Thankss

EDIT: 
i want to do something like this:

```
UiviewController current* = [delegate getCurrentView];
if(current.toString=="NotificationView"){
   [current update:notificationText];
}else{
   saveNotification;
   goToNotificationView;
}
```

Comment: view controllers has a `view` property, which is the root view for it. Is it what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most probably you have a `UINavigationController` in your main `window` (it can be a `UITabBarController`,etc), but if you have a `UINavigationController` in your main `window` then you can check the top view controller of your `UINavigationController` by using `[self.navigationController topViewController];` or you can also check for `UINavigationController`'s `viewControllers` stack that returns an array of all view controller's you pushed in `UINavigationController` and can get the last object of that `array` which is your top view by using `[[self.navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];` .

If you have a `UITabBarController` in your main `window` , then you can get the instance of `UINavigationController` (if its there) by using `[[self.tabbarcontroller viewControllers] objectAtIndex:[self.tabbarcontroller selectedIndex]];` and can do the above steps to get the top view.